# htaccess rewrite single + multiple URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to do some redirects from one domain to the other: a number of specific redirects + a general rule:

Specific redirects:

```
subdomain.example.com/ => example.com/subdomain/
subdomain.example.com/page1 => example.com/subdomain/page1
```

General rule - should apply to all URLs not captured with the above rules:

```
subdomain.example.com/* => example.com/*
```

Here are the current rules I have - the problem is that they seem to be mutually exclusive:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule /?   http://example.com/subdomain/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: which url / rule didn't work?

Comment: Only the first one works - but it takes all posts and sends them to example.com/subdomain/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect `RewriteRule` pattern, you should enclose `/?` with `^/?$`, otherwise it matches all URL.

`^`: start of line

`$`: end of line

```
# first specific rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$   http://example.com/subdomain/ [R=301,L]

# second specific rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^subdomain\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^page1$   http://example.com/subdomain/page1 [R=301,L]
```